# Laptop bios version not matching

Tags: bios, version

My laptop's bios ignited or something due to a electrical short circuit in the motherboard , thus disabling any electrical current passing through it.
I went to a technician which managed to make it work by replacing the old bios by a new one.

Turns out that he replaced the bios by another's laptop firmware which was quite similar to mine; 
My Laptop : ASUS K56CB.

New Bios Firmware belongs to : ASUS S550CM.

My Laptop is Working fine , only my NVIDIA is no longer recognized by the system nor the BIOS.

I Tried To flash the BIOS by the correct version i got from the ASUS official website, but i get:

"bios model name doesn't match asus" warning.

Any Suggestions ?

PS: the technician is no longer an option.

Comment: Can you show us the link where you got the correct BIOS version? Also, are the NVIDIA drivers installed? You can check by looking in device manager, under display adapters.

Comment: Bios link : https://www.asus.com/Laptops/K56CB/HelpDesk_BIOS/

as for the drivers i already tried everything , from automatic to manual installation ,
 i cant install any driver as i mentioned , for the system , ther's no such thing as nvidia GC

Comment: The S550CM is a different laptop... It sounds like the previous technician either replaced the BIOS chip with one from a "similar" laptop but it isn't the same or programmed it with an EEPROM programmer with the incorrect file. You will need to replace it with the correct one (there are several on eBay or from BIOS-CHIP24), which is a soldered chip in this laptop. In general, the flashing tools block flashing a non-matching BIOS, so that likely isn't an option if you don't have a stand-alone EEPROM programmer.

Comment: yes, ill buy a new one and replace it , Thank You